# QT: picture as window

Tags: c++, qt, coding-style, background, window

I want to make window frame using some picture. Window shouldn't have borders, titlebars, etc. It also should be hidden from active windows list (in taskbar).

Second part of question I did with:

```
this->setAttribute(Qt::WA_NoSystemBackground);
this->setAttribute(Qt::WA_QuitOnClose);

this->setAutoFillBackground(true);

this->setWindowFlags(Qt::FramelessWindowHint | Qt::Tool);
```

for new class which inherits `QMainWindow`. It's hidden, for example, at gnome taskbar, but in Awn (awant windows navigator) I seed it in the list of active windows :(.

What about first part. I did this some time ago with `QRegion, QPixmap` and mask in overloaded `paintEvent`. I've lost the code. Can you help me with this?

Comment: If I recall, a window is any top-level widget, and said widgets follow the rules of the OS, namely that it will have a title bar and borders as the OS dictates.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

regarding the first part of the question, you, probably, looking for smth like this:

```
void MainWindow::paintEvent(QPaintEvent * event)
{
    QPainter painter(this);

    QPixmap pixmap = QPixmap();
    pixmap.load("/home/my_image.jpg");

    painter.drawPixmap(event->rect(), pixmap);
}
```

as an alternative you can create a [label](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.7-snapshot/qlabel.html) and show it on your main window, smth like this:

```
QLabel* label = new QLabel(this); // where 'this' is your window 
label->setGeometry(this->geometry());

QPixmap pixmap = QPixmap();
pixmap.load("/home/my_image.jpg");

label->setPixmap(pixmap.scaled(label->size(), Qt::KeepAspectRatio));
```

hope this helps, regards

Comment: With first code I don't see my image as background, just an empty black rect.

Comment: I missed the right way of image. Now it draws, but still black rectangle under it.

Comment: I guess you need to post up your code; both code snippets worked fine on my ubuntu